# Implementation of Multiplayer game - Jquery Application Level?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, multithreading, dwr

Good day!

I am planning to create a multiplayer board game using java, jquery, dwr, ajax. In my java, i will store data into application level. Using dwr and ajax, I can retrieve data without the need to refresh my browser and do JQuery animation accordingly. My problem is, If there are many players, how can the JQuery animation automatically changes for everyone to see it without the need for them to refresh their browser.

For example, player 1 is on grid(1,1). My code will allow player 1 to go to grid(1,2), grid(1,3) etc. using Jquery with corresponding animation. But the other player(using another browser) will not be able to see this. How can i make the other player see it? Is it possible that the second player is also accessing the browser of player 1 remotely? Any suggestions/books/articles/code samples regarding this would do.

Thank you.

Comment: I haven't done this kind of thing before, but if I were too I would have a service layer control this.  You can set up two-way binding with a web service (WCF) so that you can pass this players moves and have the other players moves forwarded to you in the browser.  An easier alternative is the same architecture, but poll the service at intervals to see if the other player has moved.  Is that the kind of thing you're after? - See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CometAsync.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Yes.. something like that. I want the second player to see if the first player has moved without refreshing his page. I have no idea how can i do this using web service.

Comment: The link I've appended to my above comment shows the user of `Comet` and two way binding to make a browser chess game - probably not unsimilar to what you're doing.  I'll post it as an answer if that's what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can do it with Ajax by calling ajax calls every second for every user to check if there are changes on board.

2)To not to make many ajax calls you can use [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).

3)From performance view the best way is to make TCP server and use sockets. You can use [Websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or Flash socket proxy.

Comment: Websockets & Comet work not in all browsers yet. Alternative is long poll.

Comment: Comet includes iframe, script tag or ajax long polling. For browsers not supporting Websockets you can use Flash socket proxy with library who emulates Websockets, in that way you can keep to standarts and support older browsers.

Comment: Can i use the HTML5 websocket instead?